# 3 tier application with JHipster

Tags: architecture, jhipster

How can I have 3 tier application running using JHipster. With CUBA RAD can do that, why not with JHipster? The problem of CUBA is that it is not attached to a totally free front-end (Vaadin), they have extensible front-end (Angular 1, Angular 2, and React is under development). So my question is if I can deploy JHipster in 3 tier environment.

Answer (score 0):

What's your definition of a 3 tier architecture?

It seems to me that JHipster has it:

- Presentation tier is in browser: Angular 1 or 2 and soon React.
- Logic tier is Spring Boot server app exposing a REST API and using JPA Hibernate to access data
- Data tier:  Relational database, MongoDb or Cassandra

Answer (score 0):

My doubt was how could I separate it when building. I caught the solution already. Thank you. The answer has been found here: http://www.jhipster.tech/separating-front-end-and-api/.